# Calculator code minus func not working

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device

I need help with the algorithm I don't understand what im doing wrong, when I do minus func it gives a minus number (not a correct one) and when I do plus and then minus the number is really really wrong, how do i set a stop after each func and like make it calculate it properly I've tried so long to do that I just dont know what algorithm to use im pretty new at coding

```
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
buttonClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClear);
buttonPlus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlus);
buttonEquals = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEquals);
buttonMinus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMinus);
textFinal = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textFinal);
int resultValue=0;


buttonPlus.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            String s = (String) textFinal.getText();
            ResultValue = ResultValue + Integer.parseInt(s);
            textFinal.setText("");
        }
    });
buttonMinus.setOnClickListener (
    new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            String s = (String) textFinal.getText();
            ResultValue = ResultValue - Integer.parseInt(s);
            textFinal.setText("");

        }
    });

buttonEquals.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            String s = (String) textFinal.getText();
            ResultValue = Integer.parseInt(s)+ResultValue ;
            textFinal.setText(Integer.toString(ResultValue));
            ResultValue=0;
        }
    });
```

I tried entering a new int called LastAction and making it stop after one action and renew the calculation.
I tried more things that i cant rememeber.

I tried:

```
int LastAction = 0 , and if (LastAction = 1) {
String s = (String) textFinal.getText();
                    ResultValue = ResultValue - Integer.parseInt(s);
                    textFinal.setText("");}
LastAction=1;
```

Comment: What is your ResultValue type? Also usually variable do not start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private int operationType;   

     buttonMinus.setOnClickListener (
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    String s = (String) textFinal.getText();
                    ResultValue =  Integer.parseInt(s);
                    operationType = 1;
                    textFinal.setText("");

                }
            });

buttonEquals.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            String s = (String) textFinal.getText();
            switch(operationType)
            {
                  case 1:// it means minus
                        ResultValue = ResultValue - Integer.parseInt(s); 
                        break;
                  case 2:// it means add
                        ResultValue = ResultValue + Integer.parseInt(s);
                        break;
            }
            textFinal.setText(Integer.toString(ResultValue));
            ResultValue=0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: it doesnt work now it doesnt even do a minus calculation it only does X + Y and i added a buttonClear to set resultvalue to 0 and after i press clear i cant press any buttons, ugh im rly confused buy this